# Yii2 ошибка запроса к БД

Tags: php, база-данных, yii2, домен

Здравствуйте! Я в php новичок и тем более в фреймворке Yii2, и буду рад помощи от гуру в этом направлении.
Ошибка заключаеться  том, что при запросе к БД:

```
$posts = Post::find()->all();
return $this->render('index', compact('posts'));
```

Выводит ошибки такого рода:

[image: "ошибка такого рода 1 и 2"]

Пролистав вниз я заметил, что при этом из БД было взято нужное(то есть всё).

[image: "нужное"]

Подскажите, в чем моя ошибка и как её исправить.

Подключение к БД:

```
 'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=dbname',
'username' => 'username',
'password' => 'password',
'charset' => 'utf8',
```

Модель:

```
namespace app\models;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
class Post extends ActiveRecord{
    public static function tableName() {
       return 'post';
    }
}
```

Представление:

```
var_dump($posts);
```

Comment: Проверьте включено ли расширение PDO в `php.ini`?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то он включен.
http://prntscr.com/d2mg8e

Comment: Проверьте с помощью Yii2 `requirements.php`

Comment: Выводит  - http://prntscr.com/d2n9bo